Conditions on $g$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|g^n f\|_2 = 0$ for all $f \in L^2(0, 1)$
Question:
Let $g$ be a continuous, real-valued function defined on $[0,1]$. I am trying to determine, with proof, conditions on $g$ that are equivalent to the property
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \|g^n f\|_2 = 0 \quad \text{for all } f \in L^2(0, 1),
$$
where $\|g^n f\|_2 = \left( \int_0^1 |g(x)^n f(x)|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}$.
Sketch of my solution:

Since $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, it is bounded, so there exists $M \geq 0$ such that $|g(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

I then consider the expression $\|g^n f\|_2 = \left( \int_0^1 |g(x)|^{2n} |f(x)|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}$.

To analyze the limit, I use the Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT):

If $|g(x)| < 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, then $|g(x)|^{2n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, $|g(x)|^{2n} |f(x)|^2$ converges pointwise to 0.
By bounding $|g(x)|^{2n}$ by $M^{2n}$, which goes to 0 as $n \to \infty$, we can apply the DCT to conclude that $\|g^n f\|_2 \to 0$ for all $f \in L^2(0, 1)$.


Conclusion: I concluded that the necessary and sufficient condition on $g$ is that $|g(x)| < 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.


Question: I would appreciate your feedback about my solution! Thank you for any feedback!

Your conclusion is not quite correct. $|g(x)|$ could be equal to $1$ at some points.

Eg. $g(x)=2x$ for $x \le \frac 1 2 $ and $g(x)=2(1-x)$ for $x>\frac 1  2$.

Your condition $M<1$ is only sufficient indeed, and your use of DCT to prove it is overkill. Simply write
$$|g^nf|_2\le M^n|f|_2\to0.$$

The DCT, while overkill for your case as said in the comments above, is going to come in handy for the general case: we'll show that it is necessary and sufficient to have the set $E := \{x \in [0,1] \mid |g(x)| \geq 1\}$ be of zero measure.
Necessity: suppose that $g$ satisfies your condition (which is equivalent to saying that the powers of the multiplication operator $M_g : L^2 \to L^2$ converge strongly to $0$, putting it here in case this functional analytic interpretation helps someone else in the future).
Using $f = 1_E$ the indicator function of $E$, which is $L^2$ as $E$ is automatically of finite measure as a subset of a finite measure set, we get:
$$0 \leq m(E) = \int_E 1 \mathrm{d}x \leq \int_E |g(x)^n|^2 \mathrm{d}x = \|g^n 1_E\|^2_{L^2} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$$
where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure here (do note though that it could be replaced by any positive finite measure on $[0,1]$, since we will not use specific properties of the Lebesgue measure).
This provides the equality $m(E) = 0$, which is what we wanted.
Sufficiency: suppose that $m(E) = 0$.
Then, for any $f \in L^2$, we have:

On $E^c := [0,1] \setminus E$, we have $|g(x)^n f(x)|^2 \leq |f(x)|^2$ for all $n$, and $f$ is $L^2$ so $|f|^2$ is $L^1$;
On $E^c$ we also have that $g(x)^n \to 0$ since $|g(x)| < 1$, and thus $|g(x)^nf(x)|^2 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Since $m(E) = 0$, this implies that $|g^nf|^2$ satisfies the assumptions of the DCT, hence:
$$\int_E |g(x)^n f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x = \|g^n f\|^2_{L^2} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$$
Conclusion: Your condition is indeed equivalent to imposing that the set $\{x \in [0,1] \mid |g(x)| \geq 1\}$ be of zero measure.

To determine conditions on a sequence of functions


g
n
​
such that
lim
⁡

→
∞
∥



∥
2
0
n→∞
lim
​
∥g
n
​
f∥
2
​
=0
for all

∈

2
(
0
,
1
)
f∈L
2
(0,1), we need to analyze how


g
n
​
interacts with any function in the

2
L
2
space and ensures the product



g
n
​
f vanishes in the

2
L
2
-norm as

→
∞
n→∞.
Let’s proceed by examining the integral defining the

2
L
2
-norm:
∥



∥
2
(
∫
0
1
∣


(

)

(

)
∣
2


)
1
/
2
.
∥g
n
​
f∥
2
​
=(∫
0
1
​
∣g
n
​
(x)f(x)∣
2
dx)
1/2
.
We need
∥



∥
2
→
0
∥g
n
​
f∥
2
​
→0 as

→
∞
n→∞ for any

∈

2
(
0
,
1
)
f∈L
2
(0,1). This suggests that


g
n
​
must either decay in magnitude or exhibit oscillatory behavior that "averages out" in the limit, weakening its interaction with any

f.
Sufficient Condition on


g
n
​
One sufficient condition on


g
n
​
is:
lim
⁡

→
∞
∥


∥
∞



n→∞
lim
​
∥g
n
​
∥
∞
​
=0.
If
∥


∥
∞
→
0
∥g
n
​
∥
∞
​
→0, then for any

∈

2
(
0
,
1
)
f∈L
2
(0,1),
∥



∥
2
≤
∥


∥
∞
∥

∥
2
→
0
as 

→
∞
.
∥g
n
​
f∥
2
​
≤∥g
n
​
∥
∞
​
∥f∥
2
​
→0as n→∞.
This guarantees that
∥



∥
2
→
0
∥g
n
​
f∥
2
​
→0 for all

∈

2
(
0
,
1
)
f∈L
2
(0,1).
Alternative Condition Using Weak Convergence
Another approach is to require that


g
n
​
converges to zero in a weaker sense, such as in measure or distribution. Specifically, if


→
0
g
n
​
→0 in

2
(
0
,
1
)
L
2
(0,1), then
lim
⁡

→
∞
∥



∥
2
0
n→∞
lim
​
∥g
n
​
f∥
2
​
=0
for all

∈

2
(
0
,
1
)
f∈L
2
(0,1), by properties of product spaces in

2
L
2
.

it is copied in small letters and capital letter so please see only once the words it is repeated again
